# Camunda: Cannot resolve identifier for an exclusive gateway

Tags: html, xml, bpmn, camunda

I tried to use a html form for a user task in which a variable gets defined, to select a sequenzflow in the following exclusive gateway.
html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="radiobutton">
        <label>
            <input cam-variable-name="altneu" cam-variable-type="String" type="radio" name="altneu" class="form-control" value="NEU"/>
            Neukunde
        </label>
        <label>
            <input cam-variable-name="altneu" cam-variable-type="String" type="radio" name="altneu" class="form-control" value="ALT"/>
            Altkunde
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sequenceflows:

```
<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_0a0vwxr" name="Kunden-stammdaten sind vorhanden" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway_0vokx46" targetRef="ExclusiveGateway_074f3z1">
<bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${altneu == 'ALT'}]]></bpmn:conditionExpression>
</bpmn:sequenceFlow>

<bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_1cwjztj" name="Kundenstammdaten sind nicht vorhanden" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway_0vokx46" targetRef="Task_1peelfz">
<bpmn:conditionExpression xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression"><![CDATA[${altneu == 'NEU'}]]></bpmn:conditionExpression>
</bpmn:sequenceFlow>
```

I get this exception when executing:

> An error happend while submitting the task form :
>   Cannot submit task form 713c798f-ebeb-11e7-9cb1-dcfe074be7ab: Unknown property used in expression: ${altneu == 'NEU'}. Cause: Cannot resolve identifier 'altneu'

Answer (score 0):

I tested your form with camunda bpm 7.8 with the help of the tasklist and got the message, that it is not possible to instantiate a variable with the same name. This means, that the engine is not able to recognize two or more occurrences of the same variable name for the same input variable. Therefore the engine instantiates the variable "altneu" as it finds the input for "NEU". Then it finds "altneu" again and tries again to instantiate "altneu" for "ALT". But "altneu" already exists.

Please refer to [the controls section of camunda's manual](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/embedded-forms/controls/). It seems, that there is no direct support for radio buttons. If possible you can use [a select](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/embedded-forms/controls/select/)?

```
<form role="form" name="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select cam-variable-name="altneu" cam-variable-type="String">
            <option value="ALT">Alt</option>
            <option value="NEU">Neu</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Another alternative could be a checkbox.

```
<form role="form" name="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="neukundeId">Neukunde?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" cam-variable-name="isNeu" cam-variable-type="Boolean" id="neukundeId" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Otherwise camunda's hint

> If an HTML control is not supported, you need to write custom JavaScript.

is valid.